# Independent clause and part of a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, clauses

1.What is the independent clause here?
2.How does 'accidentally spilled his cargo, leaving a pulpy mess' function here?

> *Last month a porter carrying a basket of tomatoes in the crowded Shasha market in Ibadan, a city in south-western Nigeria, accidentally spilled his cargo, leaving a pulpy mess.*
> [(Source)](https://www.economist.com/middle-east-and-africa/2021/03/06/how-a-spilled-basket-of-tomatoes-paralysed-nigeria)

Comment: You've written several similar questions.  Can you tell me the source of the quotes?

Comment: What do you think is the independent clause?  What is the main verb? What is its subject?

Comment: I just want to analyze the sentences used in the articles of economist.com

Comment: Okay then,  please link to the source of the quotes.

Comment: Search in Google " economist.com"

Comment: No!  That is not my job.  You are quoting, you cite your sources!

Comment: 'accidentally spilled his cargo, leaving a pulpy mess' is what the porter did. All the intervening stuff is explanation (what he was doing at the time, where Ibadan is)

Comment: @HasanHasu Please follow James' advice and always include a source and as much information as possible in your questions. Questions without enough details or context may be closed. Please see [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). Also, when you have received a good answer, you can consider upvoting it and accepting it. See [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @ Eddie Kal ok.

Comment: The main (independent) clause here is the sentence as a whole: "Last month a porter [carrying a basket of tomatoes in the crowded Shasha market in Ibadan, a city in south-western Nigeria], accidentally spilled his cargo, [leaving a pulpy mess]". The bracketed "carrying" clause is a relative clause modifying “porter”, and hence is subordinate (dependent), and the bracketed “leaving” clause is an embedded adjunct (resultative), thus subordinate (dependent). The expression “accidentally spilled his cargo, leaving a pulpy mess” is a verb phrase functioning as the predicate of the main clause.

Answer (score 1):

> *Last month a porter* [*carrying a basket of tomatoes in the crowded Shasha market in* *Ibadan, a city in south-western Nigeria*]*,
> accidentally spilled his cargo,* [*leaving a pulpy mess*].

The main/matrix (independent) clause here is the sentence as a whole. It is not dependent on some other element.

The bracketed "carrying" clause is modifying the head noun “porter” and hence is subordinate (dependent).

The bracketed "leaving" clause is an adjunct in clause structure, and thus subordinate (dependent).

The expression “accidentally spilled his cargo, leaving a pulpy mess” is a verb phrase functioning as the predicate of the main clause (the sentence).